# showsMyLocationButton doesn't work on Apple Maps

Tags: react-native, google-maps, expo, react-native-maps, apple-maps

To display the map, I'm using react-native-maps. I want to display the button to see my location, however, it only works in Google Maps; when I switched to Apple Maps, it didn't work. Also, the Compass button didn't work too.

I'm using

- iOS 16.5.1 (20F75)
- Expo Go v2.29.2
- react-native: 0.72.3
- react-native-maps: 1.7.1
- expo: 49.0.3

Here is my code

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";

const CityDetailsScreen: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* Apple Maps for iOS and Google Maps for Android */}
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          showsCompass={true}
          showsMyLocationButton={true}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  map: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
});

export default CityDetailsScreen;
```

Here is the Apple Maps

[image: Apple Maps]

Here is the Google Maps

[image: Google Maps]

Comment: Does the react-native-maps library switches to Apple Maps if you are using apple devices? Or you just modified it yourself?

Comment: I took a look and it looks like it does. You might want to file an issue in the github repo itself.

Comment: @Yrll Yes it does. If you use the prop `provider="google"`, it will change to Google Maps.